# Adding gif from library in VS

Tags: html, css, visual-studio, razor

I would like to add a .gif from a folder called images in a project in VS. I tried using css to accomplish this by doing

```
div {
    background-image: url("~/images/loading.gif");
}
```

However, this isn't working. I have seen using the

```
<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin fa-5x"></i>
```

tag to accomplish this. However, I would like to use my own gif.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: you are not making much sense in your question.. what you have seen is `i` tag using classes. You are using the name of the tag directly..

Comment: Sorry, I have seen the <i> tag used in conjunction with bootstrap to accomplish displaying a spinning gif. I, however, wish to use a gif from my images folder.

Comment: You can't use `~` inside style sheet file! this is known for razor view engine!